# ember js - controller action not invoked

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have the following controller code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();


App.DocumentController = Ember.Controller.extend({  
  actions:{
    test:function(){
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
});
```

This the form:

```
div class="form-horizontal form-group form-group-lg row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
      {{input type="text" value=name class="form-control" placeholder="Name of document." autofocus="autofocus"}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" {{action 'test'}}>Create Document</button>
    </div>

</div>

{{#if responseMessage}}
  <div class="alert alert-success">{{responseMessage}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

When clicking the button, the debugger outputs:

Nothing handled the action 'firstAction'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble

Not sure what the problem is - the route code:

```
Router.map(function() {  
  this.resource( 'index', { path: '/' } );
  this.route('decisions');
  this.route('teams');
  this.route('about');
  this.resource("documents",{ path: '/documents' }, function() {            
        this.route('/show', {path: '/show/:id'});
        this.route('/edit', {path: ':id/edit'});
  });
});
```

The model code:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({  
  name: DS.attr('String'),
  url: DS.attr('String'),
  text: DS.attr('String')  
});
```

I know ember has a strict naming convention, but I generated the resource (documents) from the ember-cli using the naming convention in their tutorials. How do I get the template hbs code to talk to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with my folder structure. Because the document model will have alot of different templates, I decided to add a document folder inside the template folder. I should have done the same with the controller folder (i.e. added a documents folder). Also the file name of the controller needs to be the same file name as the template (in this case index.hbs for template, and index.js for controller file).

Answer (score 0):

The name of the action in your controller is `test` but you are invoking a method by the name `firstAction`, which is not defined.

try the below:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" {{action 'test'}}>Create Document</button>
```

Comment: sorry I mistyped when I wrote the question, edited the action name in the question. Still experiencing the same issue